# bpm activiti framework and database polling

Tags: java, workflow, activiti, business-process-management

I have just stated with activiti bpm and took a look at the user guide http://www.activiti.org/userguide/

I realised the bpm framework is mainly design for real time business process where the user interacts with the UI/system and performs the workflow actions.

I have a loan system, where the applicant's loan request is submitted on a daily basis, and the credit rating is not known until a day end batch jobs runs.

Is there anyway, I can wake the workflow "process" up, and checks if the applicant rating is greater than a certain value and automatically approves the loan request?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But first, you have to define your flow. There are lot of tasks to achieve what you're looking for. I suggest you to first study [BPMN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) and then go with activiti or another bpm tool.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what kind of tasks in activiti can I achieve this?

Comment: Plenty of them. But first, you have to define your flow.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza step 1. User submits a loan application. step 2. system receives the credit rating of all person from various banks and load it into the system. step 3. System retrieves all loan application and checks against the credit rating, if rating is below x, system rejects the application. if rating is above x, system approves the application

Comment: Read the flow out loud and think about it. Does the system really need to receive the credit rating of all people after a single user submits a single loan application? You should stop thinking on how the system behaves now, and think on the processes of the organization, how they currently are and which tasks can be automatized via specific system interaction or any other way e.g. email sending, batch processing, among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimus,

this is typically done with a timer event. The documentation section "8.7.1. Asynchronous Continuations"
contains an example "Wait until next business day".

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnConcurrencyAndTransactions

Regards

Rob